# NoClassDefFoundError in ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am upgrading this plugin: https://github.com/meltwater/elasticsearch-analysis-combo/tree/f3d4d365881416355e935afb966386a40325a53c
from ES 2.1.1 to ES 2.2.0 . I made the required changes in my plugin and installed it. Now when I run any request on ES , it throws **NoClassDefFoundError** for a class which is present in one of the JARs in the plugin.

I used these settings to create my index:

```
{
    "index" : {
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "default" : {
                    "type" : "custom",
                    "tokenizer" : "standard",
                    "filter" : [ "snowball", "lowercase" ]
                },
                "combo" : {
                    "type" : "combo",
                    "sub_analyzers" : [ "standard", "default" ]
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "snowball" : {
                    "type" : "snowball",
                    "language" : "english"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the request I am sending:

```
localhost:9200/testindex/_analyze?analyzer=combo&text=algorithm
```

and this is the response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "remote_transport_exception",
        "reason": "[Edward \"Ned\" Buckman][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:admin/analyze[s]]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "no_class_def_found_error",
    "reason": "Could not initialize class org.apache.lucene.util.ReaderCloneFactory"
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

ES console logs after executing above request:

```
RemoteTransportException[[Edward "Ned" Buckman][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:admin/analyze[s]]]; nested: NoClassDefFoundError[Could not initialize class org.apache.lucene.util.ReaderCloneFactory];
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.lucene.util.ReaderCloneFactory
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.ComboAnalyzer$CombiningTokenStreamComponents.createTokenStreams(ComboAnalyzer.java:204)
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.ComboAnalyzer$CombiningTokenStreamComponents.getTokenStream(ComboAnalyzer.java:195)
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer.tokenStream(Analyzer.java:182)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.analyze.TransportAnalyzeAction.simpleAnalyze(TransportAnalyzeAction.java:240)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.analyze.TransportAnalyzeAction.shardOperation(TransportAnalyzeAction.java:225)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.analyze.TransportAnalyzeAction.shardOperation(TransportAnalyzeAction.java:63)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportSingleShardAction$ShardTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportSingleShardAction.java:282)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportSingleShardAction$ShardTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportSingleShardAction.java:275)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4.doRun(TransportService.java:350)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```